# Tool To Normalize A Database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-normalization

I have a huge table with a lot of records that I want to split into smaller tables to make it normalized. I already have the model for the normalized table. Now, I want to take all the records from the huge table and split them up into the several tables that'll normalize the data.

Is there a tool to make this process easy? I'm planning to write a script in PHP to loop through the records in the huge table and and split them up into the other tables.

Comment: How can you have 5,168 rep and put a question up like this?

Comment: Well, not to be snarky but if you look at the user's profile you'll see the majority of reputation derives from SO itself, and the top tag is "php". Go figure, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ETL tools might be clever enough to allow you to split data into multiple destination tables, but I don't know of one offhand. You can try [Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/).

In my experience, these kinds of tasks are often so custom that it's necessary to write a one-off script.

Comment: More specifically: A migration script, either through a formal patching system, or just a `.sql` file with series of specific SQL statements to be executed in order, is usually how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

[NORMA](http://www.ormfoundation.org/files/folders/norma_the_software/default.aspx) for conceptual database design. One side-effect is that it produces the schema for a properly normalized database.

But the best solution is that you should be able to fully understand how to normalize forms, for how long you will be dependent on any tools to do this for you? I would suggest you to [study a bit about it](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm) so that you could come up with the best solution yourself. As a developer, you will face this every now and then, and what about an interview, let's suppose where you are asked about it? And as Mitch Wheat said, normalization should not require a tool :)

Here are some more resources to get you started:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html

Source: MySQL website (Official)

Comment: The question is not how to normalize. I already have a normalized database design. The data from the huge table is just too much to do manually. And if there is a tool to help me split the data into smaller tables, I'd rather go that route than write a one-off script.

Comment: I means you want to portioning one table data into several tables for improving DB performance.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html